# Why SetDefaultConnectionFactory is used in DbConfiguration class

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am learning the DBConfiguration class from [this](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Code-based%20Configuration) site.

```
public class MyConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public MyConfiguration()
    {
        SetDefaultConnectionFactory(new LocalDbConnectionFactory("v11.0"));
        AddProvider("My.New.Provider", new MyProviderServices());
    }
}
```

Why `SetDefaultConnectionFactory` is used here? Why it is mentioned as `Default`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used for initializing the provider connection with the front end. 
Please refer 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.defaultconnectionfactory(v=vs.103).aspx for more details about database related issues