# Missing ProviderName when debugging AzureFunction as well as deploying azure function

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure, azure-functions

I have an issue getting a `DbContext` to correctly pull my connection string from my `local.settings.json`

Context:

- This is an Azure function project
- The main problem code is in `System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig`
- Although I have a `local.settings.json` file this is not dotnet core. It's .net 4.6.1

Error message:

> 'The connection string 'ShipBob_DevEntities' in the application's configuration file does not contain the required providerName attribute."'

Json configuration:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": ""
},

"ConnectionStrings": {
"ShipBob_DevEntities": {
  "ConnectionString": "metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data source=***;initial catalog=***;persist security info=True;User Id=***;Password=***;;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework'",
  "providerName": "System.Data.EntityClient"
    }
  }
}
```

Configuration versions tested:

- Moving the provider name into the actual `ConnectionString` token value : same error ocurrs
- Setting the `provider` attribute inside the `ConnectionString` attribute to `EntityClient`: this did nothing
- Making `ShipBob_DevEntities` a string value = to the value of `ConnectionString` : this throws new errors the likes of which are

  > keyword metadata is not supported
- I tried using an ADO connection string which throws a `code first` exception which seems to occur when your connection string is incorrect in a `database first` approach.

I've taken the liberty to decompile `EntityFramework.dll` using *dotPeek* and have traced the problem down to `System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.TryInitializeFromAppConfig`. Inside this method there is a call to `LazyInternalConnection.FindConnectionInConfig` which spits out a `ConnectionStringSettings` object that has it's `ProviderName` value set to null. Unfortunately I am unable to debug the `AppConfig.cs` class which it seems to use to generate this value so I am stuck.

[image]

So far I have consulted these two articles. One of which states to put the provider name as it's own token; however, this is not working.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-cli/issues/193
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-cli/issues/46

Does anyone know the correct format to use in local.settings.json for an Entity Framework connection?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So the solution ended up being trivial. The `ProviderName` attribute specified in `local.settings.json` **MUST** be camel case.

From the original git hub discussions :
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-cli/issues/46
*Shows the provider name as being pascal case*

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-cli/issues/193
*Shows the provider name being camel case in pseudo code*
It was very easy to miss but your config section must be exactly as follows

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"ShipBob_DevEntities": {
  "ConnectionString": "metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data source=***;initial catalog=***;persist security info=True;User Id=***;Password=***;;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework'",
  "ProviderName":  "System.Data.EntityClient"
  }
}
```

These points are important:

- Make sure your connection string has metadata information
- If copying your string from an xml config, make sure you unescape apostrophes
- Make sure the `ProviderName` attribute is **camel case**
- Make sure the provider name is `System.Data.EntityClient`

### Fix for missing providername in deployment

*Note, this answer assumes you are trying to use the parameterless constructor of a DbContext. If you are creating new code you can easily follow the second upvoted answer*

I figured out a way to circumvent the provider name issue while still retaining the use of the portal config and thus deployment slots. It involves setting the default connection string of db context using static properties

```
private static string _connectionString = "name=ShipBob_DevEntities";

    static ShipBob_DevEntities()
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureFunction")))
        {
            var connectionString = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("EntityFrameworkConnectionString");

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionString))
            {
                _connectionString = connectionString;
            }
        }
    }

    public ShipBob_DevEntities()
        : base(_connectionString)
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }
```

This involves the developer to create an app setting in the azure portal as a flag. In my case it is **AzureFunction**. This makes sure that our code is only run in an azure function and all other clients of this DbContext, whether they be web apps, windows apps, etc, can still continue behaving as expected. This also involves adding your connection string to the azure portal as an **AppSetting** and not an actual connection string. Please use the full connection string including them **metadata** information but without the provider name!

### EDIT

You will need to edit your auto generated .tt file t4 template to make sure this code does not get overridden if you are using db first.

Here is a link on the T4 syntax: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/writing-a-t4-text-template

And here is an explanation on EF T4 templates: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj613116(v=vs.113).aspx#1159a805-1bcf-4700-9e99-86d182f143fe

Comment: Exactly how does this bypasses the providerName issue in production? I understand in local you're passing the ProviderName but in prod you're still missing that. Do you have any special stuff in the entityframeworkconnectionstring or is it identical to what you have in the local settings file (connectionstring) ?

Comment: Actually if you have an app.config or web.config can you please share that as well - or at least the relevant bits

Comment: Hey Mavi, so the connection string that is being read by the constructor is the same exact connection string that is found in the local.settings.json. The only difference is the `ProviderName` is left out of it. There is no need to specify that in the constructor of a db context. I'm assuming because it's already implied that the provider is entity framework if you are using a dbcontext. I do not have any `app.config` or `web.config`'s at all. I simply add the 2 keys mentioned above to my app settings in the actual portal.

Comment: Example: place this as an `appsetting` in your azure portal: `metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data source=***;initial catalog=***;persist security info=True;User Id=***;Password=***;;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework'` Then follow my code sample above to retrieve it. Make sure your property and constructors are static so they run before the instance constructors

Comment: I've hardcoded the string and I'm still getting this error

Comment: I started a chat with you so we can talk there

Comment: Oh! found what I was doing wrong! It was another method which initialized the entities without the hardcoded string (so still looking for the config values in a file). This method works. Thanks a lot Adrian

Comment: why do you use the AppSettings instead of using adding a new ConnectionString in the Portal? does this not work?

Comment: It has been a while since I've messed with this code but I believe the issue is that you cannot access the connection strings via `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable` as only the app settings are loaded as environment variables. Also there are differences in the way you access these variables in local dev and in prod. For example, I also believe you cannot access app settings in prod by using ConfigurationManager but in local you can. It should be easy to test.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Beside that I am using EF edmx from database generated. Is it a good approach to amend Auto generated Context file? it will be overwritten anyway with the next update. there should be a safer way

Comment: Also you can use ConfigurationManager to get Connection string from Azure Function settings.

Comment: Hello batmaci, I saw your answer. If it works for others awesome! In response to your question above, yes the edmx files get overwritten unless you edit the t4 templates. I mentioned that in the edit.

Comment: Batmaci, can you use ConfigurationManager to get the connection strings on a deployed environment?

Comment: I am confused. Your example uses Pascal case, but you say you **MUST** use camel case?

Comment: Pro tip: if you copy and paste the Entity Framework connection string from an app.config file, replace the &quot; by a single quote (`'`).

Answer (score 16):

I went through several similar questions and answers here. Many of them are either misleading or assuming everybody is on the same level and understands how the azure functions are working. there is no answer for newbies like me. I would like to summarize here my solution step by step. I dont think that provided answer is the best option because it forces you to change the auto generated edmx files which can be overwritten by mistake or next update of your edmx from database. Also best option here is to use Connection strings instead of App settings in my opinion.

1. most important thing is that we understand local.settings.json file
   IS NOT FOR AZURE. it is to run your app in the local as the name is
   clearly saying. So solution is nothing to do with this file.
2. App.Config or Web.Config doesnt work for Azure function connection strings. If you have Database Layer Library you cant overwrite connection string using any of these as you would do in Asp.Net applications.
3. In order to work with, you need to define your connection string on the azure portal under the `Application Settings` in your Azure function. There is 
   Connection strings. there you should copy your connection string of your DBContext. if it is edmx, it will look like as below. There is Connection type, I use it SQlAzure but I tested with Custom(somebody claimed only works with custom) works with both.

> metadata=res://*/Models.myDB.csdl|res://*/Models.myDB.ssdl|res://*/Models.myDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider
>   connection string='data source=[yourdbURL];initial
>   catalog=myDB;persist security info=True;user
>   id=xxxx;password=xxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework

4. After you set this up, You need to read the url in your application and provide the DBContext. DbContext implements a constructor with connection string parameter. By default constructor is without any parameter but you can extend this. if you are using POCO class, you can amend DbContext class simply. If you use Database generated Edmx classes like me, you dont want to touch the auto generated edmx class instead of you want to create partial class in the same namespace and extend this class as below.

This is auto generated DbContext

```
namespace myApp.Data.Models
{   

    public partial class myDBEntities : DbContext
    {
        public myDBEntities()
           : base("name=myDBEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

}
```

this is the new partial class, you create

```
namespace myApp.Data.Models
{
    [DbConfigurationType(typeof(myDBContextConfig))]
    partial class myDBEntities
    {

        public myDBEntities(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
        {
        }
    }

      public  class myDBContextConfig : DbConfiguration
        {
            public myDBContextConfig()
            {
                SetProviderServices("System.Data.EntityClient", 
                SqlProviderServices.Instance);
                SetDefaultConnectionFactory(new SqlConnectionFactory());
            }
        }
    }
```

5. After all you can get the connection string from azure settings, in your Azure Function project with the code below and provide to your DbContext
   myDBEntities is the name you gave in the azure portal for your connection string.

> ```
> var connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myDBEntities"].ConnectionString;
>
>
>  using (var dbContext = new myDBEntities(connString))
> {
>         //TODO:
> }
> ```

Comment: your approach is better than the accepted answer. Thanks a lot. However, for Step 5, I have added a base class for my repository method and extracted the connection string in there and passed that property to DBContext Ctor.

Comment: @JawandSingh indeed it is almost the same thing. If you are using POCO classes, it is easier to do that but using Database Generated Edmx file, i didnt want to change my DBContext as it might be overwritten later. therefore I did it using a partial class

Comment: Hey @batmaci I'm coming back after reviewing your answer. I just want to let others know, the difference between this answer and mine is that this answer assumes you have the luxury of newing up a new dbcontext in code. In my situation I did not have the luxury of doing that as I was reusing work units and services already written. There for my solution provides a way to continue using parameterless dbcontexts without having to specify a conection string in the constructors. Just to clarify for everyone.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work on my own project with a testdatalayer - I'm beginning to think it's not intended to work on the current version of azure functions!

Comment: @RichardGriffiths do you mean in unit test project?  maybe you can create another ticket for your issue with more details.

Comment: @batmaci I've setup another question as I've tried now publishing from VS and working from the portal (two separate functions of course) and nothing I try works. The detail on my question is regarding the first version - using the portal editor and largely following your approach. 
I think one problem is trying to stick with .net 4.6 and similar simply because of the EF datalayer project. However, my understanding is this SHOULD work lol. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50115519/azure-functions-can-compile-but-cannot-run-with-custom-datalayer-library

Comment: This works if it is the only EF Context used in your project. I have a context in class library shared between apps, but another context in a web app using the class library. Web app context is instantiated 1st, and when I create the class lib context I get "The default DbConfiguration instance was used by the Entity Framework before the 'AdminDBContextConfig' type was discovered. An instance of 'AdminDBContextConfig' must be set at application start before using any Entity Framework features or must be registered in the application's config file.  (etc)"

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the similar issue before, I would use the following approach for achieving my purpose, you could refer to it:

**local.settings.json**

```html
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=brucchstorage;AccountKey=<AccountKey>",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=brucchstorage;AccountKey=<AccountKey>",
    "sqldb-connectionstring": "Data Source=.\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=DefaultConnection;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "Bruce_SQLConnectionString": "Data Source=.\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=DefaultConnection;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"
  }
}
```

For retrieving the connection string:

```
var connString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sqldb-connectionstring"];
//or var connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Bruce_SQLConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
using (var dbContext = new BruceDbContext(connString))
{
    //TODO:
}
```

Or you could init your no-argument constructor for your `DbContext` as follows:

```
public class BruceDbContext:DbContext
{
    public BruceDbContext()
        : base("Bruce_SQLConnectionString")
    {
    }

    public BruceDbContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
    {
    }
}
```

Then, you could create the instance for your `DbContext` as follows:

```
using (var dbContext = new BruceDbContext(connString))
{
    //TODO:
}
```

Moreover, you could refer to [Local settings file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local#local-settings-file) for Azure Functions.

Comment: Thank you for the response. This is something I would gladly do; however, I'm trying to use a bunch of existing data access code which has the dbcontext being created with the parameterless constructor. I'm trying to avoid having to edit all these other services. I just took a quick look at the link you provided. This may help.

Comment: I found the issue. I will add an answer

Answer (score 0):

Here are two approaches that work for me:

**Approach 1**

- Add the connection string to the App Settings (respectively local.settings.json) in the following format:

> metadata=res://*/xxx.csdl|res://*/xxx.ssdl|res://*/xxx.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data source=xxx.database.windows.net;initial catalog=xxx;user id=xxx;password=xxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework'`

- Go to the class that extends DbContext ("TestEntities") and extend the constructor to take the connection string as argument

```
public partial class TestEntities: DbContext
{
    public TestEntities(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
    }
```

- If you want then to interact with the database you need to retrieve the connection string from the app settings and then pass it over when initializing DbContext

```
string connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("connectionStringAppSettings");

using (var dbContext = new TestEntities(connectionString))
{
// Do Something
}
```

- The problem with this approach is that every time you update the database you need to update the class "TestEntities" as it is overwritten

**Approach 2**

- The goal here is to leave the class "TestEntities" as is to avoid the issue from Approach 1
- Add the connection string to the App Settings (respectively local.settings.json) like in Approach 1
- Leave TestEntities as is

```
public partial class TestEntities : DbContext
    {
        public TestEntities ()
            : base("name=TestEntities")
        {
        }
```

- As TestEntities is partial you can extend that class by creating another one that is also partial with the same name in the same namespace. The goal of this class is to provide the constructor that takes the connection string as argument

```
public partial class TestEntities
{
    public TestEntities(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
    }
}
```

- Then you can go on like with Approach 1