# Azure Functions returning Error : Keyword not supported: 'metadata'

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an azure application that consists of an API application, Website, and Functions (originally webjobs).
All three use the same backend dlls to do all the heavy lifting and database work.  The api, website and functions are just shells.

My azure functions were working correctly and I updated the backend dlls and republished.  Since then I have been getting the "Keyword not supported: 'metadata'." error everytime I try to insert records into the database.  Since the functions are nothing but shells for functionality in the API application and the Website I ran the same functionality from them without issue.  I even ran it from our integration test project also working just fine.

I know that Azure Functions can occasionally get "Stuck" so I deleted and recreated it but still had the issue.  I am using EntityFramework 6.2
My connection string includes the metadata information and I changed the string to properly include the " .

example of my connection string (all caps are masked values)

```
metadata=res://*/Model.MYMODEL.csdl|res://*/Model.MYMODEL.ssdl|res://*/Model.MYMODEL.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="Server=tcp:MYDBAZURE.database.windows.net,1433;Database=MYDB;User ID=MYUSERNAME;Password=MYPASSWORD;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
```

I know that the azure functions rely on some underling dlls and components I can not change so I am thinking this might be the issue.

Comment: Have you referenced to this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46698103/missing-providername-when-debugging-azurefunction-as-well-as-deploying-azure-fun/)?

Comment: I will take a look.I had to switch back to my webjob based setup which has been working.  But I like the serverless way functions work.