# How to define providername attribute in Application Settings of Azure Function

Tags: entity-framework, connection-string, azure-functions, appsettings

I am trying to establish an Entity Framework database connection within my Azure function. Therefore I need to define a connection string in the application settings of the function. Just adding a connection string with my DbContext class name as key in Azure Portal leads to an exception as the providername attribute is undefined when connecting to the database. I am using Entity Framework v. 6.2.0

The Exception is:

**System.InvalidOperationException:** *'The connection string 'CloudOrchestrationEntities' in the application's configuration file does not contain the required providerName attribute."'*

Is there a way to use a json string like the one I can define in local.settings.json in the application settings in Azure portal?

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"CloudOrchestrationEntities": {
  "ConnectionString": "metadata=res://*/CloudOrchestration.csdl|res://*/CloudOrchestration.ssdl|res://*/CloudOrchestration.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data source=*****.database.windows.net;initial catalog=*****;user id=*****;password=*****;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework'",
  "ProviderName": "System.Data.EntityClient"
}
}
```

Using this json entry as connection string in Azure Portal including the provider name leads to an invalid connection string in my function code.
[image]
[image]

I surely can define the connection string [as a usual app setting and retrieve it in my function code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48152780/3218705) to connect to db but this is not the way I want this issue to be resolved. Actually I do not want to edit the auto generated EF classes as I share them with a different project.

Comment: what is th exception you re having ? which version of entity framework are you using ? It seems you re using an old version of EF ? with code first your database connectionstring should be simpler

Comment: I edited my question and added the exception message as well as the EF version that I use.

Comment: you connectionstring is the azure portal should be in the connectionstrings section. Also the name of your connectionstring should be `CloudOrchestrationEntities` and the value `metadata=res://*/CloudOrchestration.csdl|res://*/CloudOrchestration.ssdl|res://*/CloudOrchestration.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data source=*****.database.windows.net;initial catalog=*****;user id=*****;password=*****;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework'` you dont want to include the json, just value

Comment: Well actually you just copied the string that I posted above. This is exactly the setting that doesn't work as I didn't specify a providerName. 
Please read the post carefully as I describe this in the first paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to specify the provider name to be `System.Data.EntityClient` on Azure, only `System.Data.SqlClient` and `MySql.Data.MySqlClient`.

There are some workarounds and possible solutions in this question [Missing ProviderName when debugging AzureFunction as well as deploying azure function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46698103/3234163)