# Azure function with EF 6 datbase first model - connection strings concern

Tags: entity-framework-6, azure-functions, connection-string

When i run my app from visual studio - it works fine, so the connection string is ok.
Whereas when i add the function into Azure and i enter the connection string here :

[image]

No  matter what I enter the error comes back as :

[image]

Here is my latest connection string :

```
metadata=res://*/CatModel.csdl|res://*/CatModel.ssdl|res://*/CatModel.msl;
provider=System.Data.SqlClient;providerName=System.Data.EntityClient;
provider connection string='data source=xxx.database.windows.net;initial catalog=CatsDB;
user id=xxx;password=!;
MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
App=EntityFramework
```

Any help would be amazing because i have been testing connection strings for hours...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50794441/how-to-define-providername-attribute-in-application-settings-of-azure-function

Comment: anyone got any ideas ??? This is just crazy how this doesn't work